# Syntax error i think causing many errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, syntax, maps

I need help with my current code. I am trying to have Google Places onto my app. These are the errorsI get:

-**map cannot be resolved or is not a field**
MainActivity.java   /MultiNAV/src/com/multinav  line 50 Java Problem

-**main cannot be resolved or is not a field**
MainActivity.java   /MultiNAV/src/com/multinav  line 99 Java Problem

-**activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field** 
MainActivity.java   /MultiNAV/src/com/multinav  line 42 Java Problem

-**error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag**
activity_main.xml   /MultiNAV/res/layout    line 37 Android AAPT Problem

-**item_list cannot be resolved or is not a field** 
MainActivity.java   /MultiNAV/src/com/multinav  line 205    Java Problem

-**textView cannot be resolved**
MainActivity.java   /MultiNAV/src/com/multinav  line 208    Java Problem

-**autoCompleteTextView1 cannot be resolved or is not a field** 
MainActivity.java   /MultiNAV/src/com/multinav  line 113    Java Problem

-**googleAPIKey cannot be resolved or is not a field**
MainActivity.java   /MultiNAV/src/com/multinav  line 159    Java Problem

-**activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field** 
MainActivity.java   /MultiNAV/src/com/multinav  line 110    Java Problem

-**item_list cannot be resolved or is not a field** 
MainActivity.java   /MultiNAV/src/com/multinav  line 111    Java Problem

Here is the code:
Activity_main.xml

```
:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<!--
     Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- This can go anywhere in your layout (see other demos for some examples). -->    
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#dddddd">
    <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mapButton">
    </AutoCompleteTextView> 
  <fragment
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.multinav;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.R;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (googleMap == null){
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (googleMap != null){
                setUpMap();
            }
        }

    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Get the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Get Current Location
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // Set map type
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        // Get latitude of the current location
        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

        // get longitude of the current location
        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

        // Create a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Show the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        //Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("BAAMMMM!"));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
public class Main extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    public AutoCompleteTextView textview;

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);
            final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.item_list);
            final AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                    findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
            adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
            textView.setAdapter(adapter);
             textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (count%3 == 1) {
    adapter.clear();
                    GetPlaces task = new GetPlaces();
                            //now pass the argument in the textview to the task
                                    task.execute(textView.getText().toString());
        }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
    int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

    });
}

    class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

    @Override
                   // three dots is java for an array of strings
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... args)
    {

    Log.d("gottaGo", "doInBackground");

    ArrayList<String> predictionsArr = new ArrayList<String>();


    try
    {

        URL googlePlaces = new URL(
                "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=" +
                URLEncoder.encode(args[0], "UTF-8") +
                "&types=geocode&language=en&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyAkt0K6luIIWURTJ4kV07-S5TnqLMvD5js" +
                getResources().getString(R.string.googleAPIKey));
                URLConnection tc = googlePlaces.openConnection();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        tc.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                                //take Google's legible JSON and turn it into one big string.
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                }
                                //turn that string into a JSON object
                JSONObject predictions = new JSONObject(sb.toString()); 
                               //now get the JSON array that's inside that object            
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(predictions.getString("predictions"));

                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                                        //add each entry to our array
                        predictionsArr.add(jo.getString("description"));
                    }
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {

    Log.e("MultiNAV", "GetPlaces : doInBackground", e);

    } 
    catch (JSONException e)
    {

    Log.e("MultiNAV", "GetPlaces : doInBackground", e);

    }

    return predictionsArr;

    }

    //then our post

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result){

    Log.d("MultiNAV", "onPostExecute : " + result.size());
    //update the adapter
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.item_list);
    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    //attach the adapter to textview
    textview.setAdapter(adapter); 

    for (String string : result){

    Log.d("MultiNAV", "onPostExecute : result = " + string);
    adapter.add(string);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    Log.d("MultiNAV", "onPostExecute : autoCompleteAdapter" + adapter.getCount());


        }

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatch in the XML. Every opened statement with `<>` has to have a counterpart with `</>` to close it (opening/closing at same statement works too).

The following is what is missing a closing statement:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#dddddd">
```

Simply add a `</RelativeLayout>` where you want it - presumably in the second to last line.

Comment: So, I did this, and I actually had this on there earlier and it now says:
Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag RelativeLayout activity_main.xml /MultiNAV/res/layout line 24 Android Lint Problem
And that is just for the Activity_main.xml. The rest of the errors on the MainActivity.java still exist.

Comment: Update: I actually cleaned some stuff up and I am only down to 5 errors and none of which are in the activity_main.xml code. Its all in the MainActivity.java code. Here are the errors:

Comment: list_item cannot be resolved or is not a field      MainActivity.java /MultiNAV/src/com/multinav line 110 Java Problem
activity_list_item cannot be resolved or is not a field MainActivity.java /MultiNAV/src/com/multinav line 111 Java Problem
list_item cannot be resolved or is not a field      MainActivity.java /MultiNAV/src/com/multinav line 42 Java Problem
googleAPIKey cannot be resolved or is not a field    MainActivity.java /MultiNAV/src/com/multinav line 159 Java Problem
list_item cannot be resolved or is not a field       MainActivity.java /MultiNAV/src/com/multinav line 205 Java Problem

Comment: @user2238206 `activity_list_item` and `list_item` are not included in the .xml file. If you want to access something through `R.layout`, it has to be in the activity's layout-file (the xml file in your shown code). Every `View` in the layout file gets converted into a generated .java file when compiling - so you can't call something that isn't there. [More info here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Comment: I understand that, but "list_item.xml" is actually a layout that I created. It is there. I wasn't really worried about that error due to the fact that I had it working before I got my "RelativeLayout" error above. When I tweeked with that, I ended up somehow getting an error with "list_item". When I first put in the code, I got everything right except for a syntax error. Once I fixed that, i got the "RelativeLayout" error and then it just started giving me errors until then. So, "list_item" is there.

Comment: Any more suggestions, Im so lost?

Comment: Check your generated R.java-file from the resources - it should contain those fields, if not and you have the xml files and everything in order it's probably a build fault. You can search the internets for errors on generating the R file